# Can I pass more than one XML at a time in a rest Client

Tags: rest

Is it possible to pass more than one XML to a rest client. I am trying to pass multiple list type parameter. So I want to send all as XML

Comment: What resource is such a request supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap multiple xmls as one

ex:

```
<main>
     <e1>
       //entire xml structure for 1st xml
     </e1> 
     <e2>
      //entire xml structure for 2nd xml
     </e2>
</main>
```

Comment: I can combine them and make them one, but is it possible to send two XMLs as parameters

Comment: I am not sure what technology you're using, but it can be done with asp.net mvc (pass multiple xml parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with multipart/form-data media type: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

You can even send documents of different types(application/xml, application/json, image/png) in a single request.